# Problem with MDAC using windows 7

Tags: c#, database, excel, mdac

I'm working on an application using c# that needs to connect to a database to get the information of excel file that I have.

The problem is that until i did a registry clean, I always get the follow error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The .Net Framework Data Providers
>   require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install
>   Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later.   ---->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Retrieving the COM class
>   factory for component with CLSID
>   {2206CDB2-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A829} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I dont know if the registry clean was, but its the only thing that could do anything.
Im using **windows 7** and i read that it already includes in the core the component and i cant reinstall it.

What can i do? Seems that any of the solutions that i'm finding isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an incompatibility issue (see [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589/en-us)), here is an extract from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components):
Windows 7 SP1 has broken backwards compatibility of MDAC 2.8. Software compiled on Windows 7 SP1 that relies on MDAC ADO will not work on Windows versions prior to Windows 7 SP1 (including Windows 7 RTM, Vista, XP).[62] Microsoft has provided solutions to work around this issue for some applications but VBA applications remain affected.[63]

Comment: I dont think that will be that incompatibility. The symptomps arent like my error... I get a message problem with MDAC. And i know that w7 use another component (an upgrade of mdac), so... is not a problem with my code and w7, because two days ago, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling your application to the x86 platform?